# Can't understand cube projection algorithm. (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, graphics, 3d, ascii-art

I've been exploring a Python code that generates a rotating 3D cube animation using ASCII characters in a terminal window. The code employs a projection algorithm to project the cube's 3D coordinates onto a 2D screen.

Here's the [complete code](https://www.mail-archive.com/kragen-hacks@canonical.org/msg00237.html). and here's the snippet of the relevant code:

```py
# Relevant snippet
proj = [(round(w/2+xm*x/(z+2)), round(h/2+ym*y/(z+2))) for x, y, z in cube]
```

In this line, the variable proj calculates the projected 2D coordinates of the cube's vertices. However, I'm trying to understand the significance of adding '2' to the 'z' coordinate within the projection equation.

I've observed that altering this value significantly affects the appearance of the cube.

Can someone explain why we are adding '2' and why not any other value?

Comment: the addition of '2' is a simple method to introduce a perspective effect in the ASCII-based 3D cube rendering, and the choice of '2' is likely based on visual preferences and the desired level of perspective in the animation.

Comment: I can't run it due to a syntax error (potentially written in Python 2?) but I think `+2` is a z offset that will make the cube appear larger / smaller

Comment: @OM222O yes I too got the syntax error. Its due to the list comprehension syntax in the line where the cube is defined. I fixed it by adding parentheses to create tuples. Also you are right about the +2 being a z offset. Decreasing the offset increased the proximity and Increasing it made it look like its farther away. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The reason I wasn't able to figure it out was because I altered the code to add edges to the cube and changing the value added to z had a significant impact..sometimes it did not even look like a cube.